# Appium/Unittest/Python - preventing app from running again each test

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, junit, appium

Ok please look at my example code

My ConnectBase class:

```
class ConnectBase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = '4cfe4b59'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.0'
        desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.xyz.bookshelf'
        desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.xyz.bookshelf.MainActivity'
        desired_caps['noReset'] = False
        self.driver_android = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
        self.driver_android.implicitly_wait(30)
```

And my main file with tests:

```
import unittest
from connect import ConnectBase
from main_screen import MainScreenCheck

class MainTests(ConnectBase, MainScreenCheck):
    with open('report.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write("----------Bookshelf----------\n")

    def test_bookshelf_tutorial(self):
        self.addToFile("Test Tutorial")
        self.driver_android.orientation = 'LANDSCAPE'
        super(MainTests, self).logout_screen_check()

    def test_bookshelf_2(self):
        self.addToFile("Test 2")
        super(MainTests, self).login_screen_check()

    def test_bookshelf_3(self):
        self.addToFile("Test 3")
        super(MainTests, self).loading_screen_check()

    def test_bookshelf_4(self):
        self.addToFile("Test 4")
        super(MainTests, self).list_check()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MainTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

1. I run script -> it is connecting
2. It starts "test_bookshelf_tutorial()"
3. Test passed and i would like to continue with "test_bookshelf_2()" but the app is restarting... and i have to go throught tutorial screen again...

The problem is that every unittest "def test_xyz(self)" application is restarting so I can't use unittest function that shows the passed test in report becouse, each test I must go through everything that I made in tests before

I created my way to make a test report -> I'm adding each test result to txt file... but I wonder if there is a possibility to turn off this app restarting and use normal unittest reports?

Or maybe there is another great way to do reports of automation tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make an order to your test cases, some times test depend from each other 
in the first step open the application and close it only in the last step:

```
class MainTests(ConnectBase, TestCase):
  def step1(self):
      #open the application

  def step2(self):
      ...

  def steps(self):
    for name in sorted(dir(self)):
      if name.startswith("step"):
        yield name, getattr(self, name) 

  def test_steps(self):
    for name, step in self.steps():
      try:
        step()
      except Exception as e:
        self.fail("{} failed ({}: {})".format(step, type(e), e)
```

- I suggest that you use a Test framework like 'TESTNG' to define test priority to manage tests order but be sure that the first test is always executed to open the application ;)